# Get integer before float's decimal point (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

I have a float like so `23.248500`. Is it possible for me to just get the `23` part and the `0.248500` part separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For positive numbers, you can use [`floor(f)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/floor/) function to get `23`, and `f - floor(f)` to get the `0.248500` part.

(I linked C++ reference, but the same function is present in the C library).

Comment: @CoreCode `f` is the assumed name of your variable; I am subtracting `floor(f)` from it.

Comment: This will fail for negative numbers.  E.g. for `f == -23.248500`, `floor(f) == -24` and `f - floor(f) == 0.7515`.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks for the clarification, I fixed the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

The right function for this is [`modf()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/modf.3.html).

Comment: +1 Really good this one! I was having problems with floor(), getting 0.9999 instead of 1.0 and with modf() everything work like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
float f = 23.248500;
int a = (int)f;
float f_minus_a = f - a;
```